# SQL error on limit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblCustomers AS c ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No INNER JOIN
                      dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.maxscheddate AS m ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No LIMIT 10;
```

but I get an error saying Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'. What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblCustomers AS c ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No INNER JOIN
    dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.maxscheddate AS m ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No
```

SQL Server uses [TOP N](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463(v=sql.100).aspx) syntax instead of `LIMIT N`

Comment: Also, use TOP in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause to limit the result set to the first N number of ordered rows; otherwise, it returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx